# How to save object of the Assembly class to disk in .NET

Tags: .net

I have assemvly encoded into Base64 string on disk.
It's needed it dll representation. I can load it into Assembly object,
but could not find way to save it. Thanks!

So, 1) how to save object of the Assembly class to disk?
    2) how to save base64 encoded assembly to binary dll? [answered]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just treat it as binary - So use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get a `byte[]`, and write that:

```
string base64 = File.ReadAllText(base64path);
byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
File.WriteAllBytes(binaryPath, binary);
```

For info, in terms of runtime objects; `AssemblyBuilder` has a `.Save(...)`; but `Assembly` does not.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I interested in another way, how to save object of the Assembly class to disk?

Comment: @Alexander as I tried to note; unless you have an `AssemblyBuilder`, nothing direct is presented.

Comment: @MarcGravell - A question to the master - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081390/is-there-an-off-the-shelf-implementation-of-the-razorlights-icachingprovider-th I am OK with indirect ways, my problem is I do not see any way...