# How to add reference to a dynamic assembly for compiling another assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, .net-assembly

How would I add a dynamically loaded assembly as a reference to the `CompilerParameters.RerencedAssemblies` collection? I know I can add a reference by `Assembly.Location`, but my dynamically loaded assembly has no location. It is in the AppDomain though. But I cannot find a way to add it as a referenced assembly. Storing it in the GAC is no option.

I tried to serialize it to disk and then add it as a reference, but that fails miserably. (The serialized assembly is not a valid dll).

Any thoughts? (.Net 4.5)

BTW, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040825/how-to-add-reference-to-a-dynamic-assembly-for-compiling-another-dynamic-assembl), but it got no answers. And it's pretty old, so that's why I'm asking it again.

Comment: How is that dynamic assembly loaded ? Where is it loaded from ?

Comment: The assembly is uploaded to a DB (3th party app). The 3th party app loads this Assembly with `Assembly.Load` (outside my control). And this loaded assembly has references. Which are loaded in the AppDomain, but with an empty Location since they are not in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need [AssemblyBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

If your dynamic assembly was built using `AssemblyBuilder`, [Here is what MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) about dynamic assemblies.

> A persistable dynamic assembly is saved using the AssemblyBuilder.Save method. The Save method specifies the name of the file to which the assembly should be written.

You can use the [Save method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.save(v=vs.110).aspx) to save it to file and then use the assembly location for adding reference.

Comment: I cannot cast my assembly to an AssemblyBuilder. I can see my assembly loaded in the AppDomain (no Location).

Comment: Check out the answer to this discussion, the object of Assembly class does not have a way to be saved to disk. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856376/how-to-save-object-of-the-assembly-class-to-disk-in-net

Comment: Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830160/c-sharp-referencing-a-type-in-a-dynamically-generated-assembly

Comment: I know an `Assembly` (actually, it's of Type `RuntimeAssembly`) has no method 'Save'. In order to save it, one should use the `AssemblyBuilder`. But a `RuntimeAssembly` cannot be casted to an `AssemblyBuilder`. I don't see how your second comment helps me out. It talks about referencing types in dynamic assemblies.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, either your 3rd Party Library should give you reference to `AssemblyBuilder` somehow or look for alternate libraries that might. It won't hurt to ask the vendor of your library if there is a way to save your assembly.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But then I'll have to wait until 3022 I guess. Thanks anyway!